# Inserting space between the string (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `Manufacturers` which contains a column `Name` with a data type of `Varchar(100)` that has 5761 entries such as `XYZ(XYZ Corp)`.

I wish to insert a space between the `Z` and the `(`.

I have seen the `STUFF` and `LEFT` commands but can't seem to figure out if they apply to my scenario.

Comment: Check out `REPLACE()` function. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: BTW, tables have _rows_ and _columns_, not entries or fields. And STUFF and LEFT are functions, not commands.

Comment: Check out https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-of-the-sql-replace-function/

Answer (score 3):

You can try the [REPLACE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
 function as shown below.

```
update <yourTableName>
set <yourColumName> = replace(<yourColumName>, '(', ' ( ')
where <put the conditions here>
```

Here is an implementation to you.

```
create table test (Name varchar(20))
insert into test values ('XYZ(XYZ Corp)')

--selecting before update
select * from test

--updating the record
update test
set Name = replace(Name, '(', ' (')
where name like '%(%'  --Here you can add the conditions as you want to restrict the number of rows to be updated based on the available data or the patterns.   

--selecting after update
select * from test
```

[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=19ade0bb79154921d5e5485a7419dc33)

Comment: Nice answer, but it is perhaps worth warning that it will add a double space if there is already one before the parenthesis

Comment: If just some rows need to be updated, it's a good idea to add a WHERE clause to keep the transaction size down.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for the tip,  this is exactly the case!

Comment: also thanks @SurajKumar.   There are other entries in there that have the proper spacing i am looking for and do not wish to add a second to them.

Comment: @JMD Finding the pattern may be the logical/tricky one based on the different data available in the database and may be different logic needed.

Comment: @JMD You can accept the answer see how at https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @SurajKumar I used as suggested and then ran it again to remove the double space!  Thanks again.

Comment: @JMD I recently also done the exact case in one of my table where it was required to put the comma at the last and in some of the data comma was already there at the last. So, I added a comma first and then replace the double comma with the single one.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
update Manufacturers
    set name = replace(name, '(', ' (')
    where name like '%[^ ](%';
```

This will only update rows where there is not already a space before the open paren.

Note:  If you have multiple open parens, it will update all of them.  If that is an issue, ask a new question with appropriate sample data.